# Expo Client + Firebase javascript SDK Authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, expo

I have been trying to develop an App with Expo Client + Firebase Javascript SDK. I am using redux(redux-thunk) to manage state.  However I am having some problems to authenticate the user because every Firebase call I make, it just executes if I force the live reload of the app or if I tap anywhere.

```
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import { Actions } from "react-native-router-flux";
import {
  LOGIN,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,  
} from "./types";
import { FirebaseService } from "../services";
import i18n from "../i18n";
import * as Facebook from "expo-facebook";
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";

export const login = (email, password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);

    dispatch({ type: LOGIN });

    FirebaseService.signIn(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: user });
        Actions.tabbar();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL });
        if (error) {
          Alert.alert(
            i18n.t("app.attention"),
            i18n.t("login.enter.message"),
            [{ text: i18n.t("app.ok") }],
            { cancelable: true }
          );
        }
      });
  };
```

I called this action creator when a button is pressed and the  FirebaseService.signIn(email, password) is

```
static async signIn(email, password) {
    return await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
```

firebase was initialized with the right credentials. To be clearer, dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: user }); will only be dispatched if I tap the screen anywhere or if I cause the hot reload. Otherwise, nothing happens and the app stay on hold.  Do you have any clue of what could it be?

I am running it in an Iphone via Expo Client.

Comment: It's not clear to me the behavior you're observing.  Could you edit the question to be more specific about how this code doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Is it clearer?